# How to distinguish structurally identical types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that has several interfaces that are structurally equivalent. Like this:

```js
interface DataType { ... some stuff here ... }
interface DataTypeBoolean extends DataType {}
interface DataTypeJSON extends DataType {}
... around 20 more, not all of them equivalent
```

And it gives me an object whose type is:

```js
def: {
    flag: {
        type: DataTypeBoolean;
    };
    data: {
        type: DataTypeJSON;
    };
}
```

I want to generate a type that translates these into primitive types:

```js
export type Types<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends { type: DataTypeBoolean } ? boolean :
  T[K] extends { type: DataTypeJSON } ? object :
  ... some more clauses
  undefined;
}
```

But because `DataTypeBoolean` and `DataTypeJson` are equivalent, `DataTypeJSON` yields `true` for `extends DataTypeBoolean` and thus, `Types<def>` gives me:

```js
def: {
    flag: boolean;
    data: boolean;
}
```

For that `Types<def>` to work, I'd have to find some way to create `DataTypeBooleanStrict` and `DataTypeJsonStrict` such that `DataTypeBooleanStrict extends DataTypeBoolean` and `DataTypeJSONStrict extends DataTypeJSON` (so I can still respect the library interfaces), but also `DataTypeBooleanStrict` does not extend `DataTypeJSONStrict` and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

It would be very nice to achieve that with a generic type like `Strict<DataTypeBoolean>` instead of having to define all 30 of these manually, but manually is also better than nothing.

Comment: I don't think you can, because the TS type system is structural, that is, it doesn't care how your stuff is named. A realistic option would be to use tagged unions so that your types become structurally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it has been noted, the type system in TypeScript is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and thus two types with the same shape are actually the same type, even though they may have different *names*.  The way to deal with this is generally to modify your types so that they differ structurally as well as nominally, as mentioned in the TypeScript FAQ entry: ["How do I prevent two types from being structurally compatible?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible)

Now in this case the offending interfaces are apparently in a library that you can't or don't want to touch.  Luckily, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to re-open interface definitions and add new properties to them.  Probably you want to add something optional so that it's okay that no actual such properties exist at runtime.  For example:

```
///// DECLARATION MERGING //////
interface DataTypeBoolean {
    __type?: "boolean"
}
interface DataTypeJSON {
    __type?: "JSON"
}
///////////////////////////////
```

Keep in mind that if you are importing your interfaces from a module, you might need to use `declare module` around your merged definitions, [as shown in the Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) like

```
declare module "./myLib" {
  interface DataTypeBoolean {
      __type?: "boolean"
  }
  interface DataTypeJSON {
      __type?: "JSON"
  }
}
```

---

Anyway, once we do that, things should start to work for you, as the compiler can see that those types are different:

```
type Hmm = Types<Def>;
/* type Hmm = {
    flag: boolean;
    data: object;
} */
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#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)

Comment: This is much better than I expected! TIL about declaration merging on types that comes from external dependencies. Awesome.

Comment: Following your suggestion I was able to simplify my Types<T> generic. Having `declare module 'theLib' {
  interface DataTypeBoolean { __type?: boolean }` I could use just: `export type Types<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends { type: { __type?: infer U } } ? U : undefined;
}`.